# Measure time needed to load webpage in FF with/without ABP/Ghostery/etc

Tags: firefox, time, firefox-addon

I have the project of coding on a FF addon to speed up the time needed to download/draw all the component of a webpage. 
Deleting ads, 3rd party scripts (google analytics, etc.) but also images (do I really need to download or load from cache the stackoverflow/wikipedia/google/etc. logo ?..).

In order to do this and choose what makes me win time and what makes me lose time (too big parsing list, best way to parse, etc.), I need to be able to measure the time spent between I hit Enter key, and page is ready.

Do you know a way to do this in FF ?
Do you know a way to do this outside FF ? (so I can test with the original source / my edited source).
In second case I still need to measure time spent parsing the source file, I can do this easily by making a binary doing it but will this be relevant compared to the executing speed for FF addons ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) doesn't suit your needs, you can try [dynaTrace](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html)